# Remove the rights of the child user after updating the parent

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I use mongoose, and I need, in case the owner decided to stop paying for access to a certain brand (or tab, or type), for example, to remove it from a child.

Child Document

```
{
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "childId"
    },
    "firstName": "childname",
    "lastName": "childname",
    "email": "childmail@gmail.com",
    "password": "hashpass",
    "avatar": "avatar",
    "active": true,
    "grant": {
        "analytic": {
            "brands": true,
            "competition": true,
            "advanced": true,
            "settings": true
        },
        "entity": {
            "brands": [
                "62b602fab0513b08cbbc58cf",
                "5e2b64350abd833af61c8186"
            ],
            "competitors": [
                {
                    "competitors": [
                        "628cf4763b65341158242c97",
                        "5e2b64350abd833af61c8186",
                        "62226613937930680ce70de7"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "competitors": [
                        "62226613937930680ce70de7",
                        "628cf4763b65341158242c97",
                        "62b602fab0513b08cbbc58cf"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "categorys": [
                "5f31a884d318436258f1c1ef",
                "5e2081c80a44092668c29a47",
                "5e20856d0a44092668c29a48",
            ],
            "providers": [
                "5f52869819f2df47af4afafa",
                "5f5a4c51a030d76e5ed555f7",
                "5dc2aff3e820a760dd23f6af",
                "5f59200da030d76e5ed54e21",
            ],
            "types": [
                "structure",
                "point of interest"
            ],
            "limits": []
        },
        "user": {
            "historical_data": true,
            "allowAndUpdate": true
        }
    },
    "pId": {
      "$oid": "63add6ae1cf67918efa856c9"
    },
    "crdAt": {
      "$date": {
        "$numberLong": "1672337405101"
      }
    },
    "updAt": {
      "$date": {
        "$numberLong": "1672337405101"
      }
    },
    "__v": 0
  }
```

Parent Document

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "parentId"
  },
  "firstName": "parentname",
  "lastName": "parentname",
  "email": "parentemail@gmail.com",
  "password": "hashpass",
  "avatar": "pass",
  "active": true,
  "grant": {
    "analytic": {
        "brands": true,
        "competition": false,
        "advanced": true,
        "settings": true
    },
    "entity": {
        "brands": [
            "62b602fab0513b08cbbc58cf",
            "5e2b64350abd833af61c8186"
        ],
        "competitors": [
            {
                "_id": "62b602fab0513b08cbbc58cf",
                "competitors": [
                    "628cf4763b65341158242c97",
                    "5e2b64350abd833af61c8186"
                ]
            },
            {
                "_id": "5e2b64350abd833af61c8186",
                "competitors": [
                    "62226613937930680ce70de7",
                    "628cf4763b65341158242c97",
                    "62b602fab0513b08cbbc58cf"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "categorys": [
            "5f31a884d318436258f1c1ef",
            "5e2081c80a44092668c29a47"
        ],
        "providers": [
            "5f52869819f2df47af4afafa",
            "5f5a4c51a030d76e5ed555f7",
            "5dc2aff3e820a760dd23f6af"
        ],
        "types": [
            "structure",
            "point of interest"
        ],
        "limits": []
    },
    "user": {
        "child_users": true,
        "historical_data": true,
        "allowAndUpdate": true
    }
  },
  "crdAt": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1672337070171"
    }
  },
  "updAt": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1672337107440"
    }
  },
  "__v": 0
}
```

Both users (child and owner) have their objects with access stored in the database, and we need to subtract the owner object from the child object

the unset function in mongo is powerless here( I've been struggling with this problem for a week now

Comment: The `owner` isn't mentioned anywhere in the object you posted. Could you post the actual example? If you do, please replace any sensitive data with placeholders, and remove the unneeded key:value pairs from the example. Or, in case I'm misunderstanding, does the object you posted contain the desired output / result after updating? If it does, could you post the original (the one containing both the child and the owner)?

Comment: @FiddlingAway I put this data in the text of the question. Take a look, please